# Convert exponential to normal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, preprocessing, normalization

For the distribution shown below, I want to convert the exponential distribution to a normal distribution. I want to do this is as part of data pre-processing so that the classifier can better interpret the feature (named `ipc` here).

[image: Distribution of ipc feature]

The regular log transformation does not work here because of the (x-axis) spread.

How can I transform this data to a normal distribution?

A related answer has been pointed out in the comment but I am looking for some Python code excerpt as well.

Thanks

Comment: If those ipc values are discrete then it cannot be done - at least not deterministically. If they are continuous, and you can assume a p.d.f., then it would be possible. Are they discrete (it looks so on the graph)?

Comment: I have another metric which is continuous and has an exponential distribution. So how can I convert for that metric?

Comment: Related, on [stats.SE]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154396/translate-exponential-distribution-into-normal-distribution

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks, I actually saw that but was hoping for some code to achieve that. I should probably highlight this requirement in my question as well.

Comment: In that case I think this question might be better off on [SO]. I don't know this site's scope all that well but I don't think simple code requests are on topic. Be aware that on SO they will expect you to have put in some effort yourself.

Comment: Write it yourself. The inverse normal CDF in that recipe is accessible through what [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm) calls the _percent point function_ (ppf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np

ey = np.random.exponential(size=100)
cdfy = scipy.stats.expon.cdf(np.sort(ey))
invcdf = scipy.stats.norm.ppf(cdfy) # a normal distribution
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer` (or `sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer`) which does exactly what you want:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer
import numpy as np

ey = np.random.exponential(size=100)
qt = QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal')
no = qt.fit_transform(ey.reshape(-1, 1))
```

You can plot histograms to compare "before" vs "after":

```py
# Plot histograms to see before vs after.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.hist(ey, bins='auto')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.hist(no, bins='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The advantage of this approach is that it will also work for other input distributions, not only exponential.